# Frequently cannot connect to OWA or Outlook without rebooting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook-web-access

On my Surface Pro 3, I frequently cannot connect to OWA using Internet Explorer or Outlook 2013 without rebooting.  In Outlook, it hangs on "trying to connect" and closing/reopening Outlook does not help.  Neither does toggling "work offline" on and off.

Here's the kicker - when this starts happening I *can* still access OWA using Chrome without fail - but not using IE!  Rebooting usually fixes the problem, although I've had to reboot twice a couple of times.

The problem occurs every 1-2 days and just started happening a week or two ago.  I have all the latest updates installed through Windows Update.

Any idea what could be causing my connectivity issues in both IE and Outlook but not in Chrome??  And why rebooting is the only fix?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: @Scorpion99: Even if he is, wouldn't that affect IE and Chrome equally?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome can have their own settings

Comment: I don't believe I'm using a proxy - how would I check?  It could be something my IT department configured.